# MongoDB 2.6 Production Ready Text Search - How To Use Skip For Pagination

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

In MongoDB 2.6, the text-search is supposedly production ready and we can now use `skip`.  I'd like to use text-search and skip for pagination in my, but I'm not yet sure how to implement it.

Right now, I'm using Mongoose and the Mongoose-text-search plugin, but I don't believe either of them support `skip` in MongoDB's text search, so I guess I'll need to use the native MongoClient...

My app connects to the database via Mongoose using:

```
//Bootstrap db connection
var db = mongoose.connect(config.db, function(e) {
```

Now, how can I use the native `MongoClient` to execute a full text search for my Products model, with a `skip` parameter.  Here is what I had using Mongoose and Mongoose-text-search, but there is no way to add in `skip`:

```
 Product         =   mongoose.model('Product')

 var query       =   req.query.query;
 var skip        =   req.query.skip;
 var options     =   {
                                project: '-created',      // do not include the `created` property
                                filter: filter,           // casts queries based on schema
                                limit: 20,
                                language: 'english',
                                lean: true
                            };
Product.textSearch(query, options, function (err, response) {
});
```

Answer (score 2):

The main difference introduced in 2.6 versions of MongoDB is that you can issue a "text search" query using the standard `.find()` interface so the old methods for `textSearch` would no longer need to be applied. This is basically how modifiers such as `limit` and `skip` can be applied.

But keep in mind that as of writing the current Mongoose dependency is for an earlier version of the MongoDB node driver that existed prior to the release of MongoDB 2.6. As Mongoose actually wraps the main methods and does some syntax checking of it's own, it is probably likely ( as in untried by me ) that using the Mongoose methods will currently fail.

So what you will need to do is get the underlying driver method for [**`.find()`**](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/collection.html#find), and also now use the [**`$text`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/text/) operator instead:

```
Product.collection.find(
    { "$text": { "$search": "term" } },
    { "sort": { "score": { "$meta": "textScore" } }, "skip": 25, "limit": 25 },
    function(err,docs) {

      // processing here
});
```

Also noting that [**`$text`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/text/) operator does not sort the results by "score" for relevance by default, but this is passed to the "sort" option using the new [**`$meta`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/meta/#sort) operator, which is also introduced in MongoDB 2.6.

So alter your `skip` and `limit` values and you have paging on text search results and with a cursor. Just be wary of large data returns as `skip` and `limit` are not really efficient ways to move through a **large** cursor. Better to have another key where you can range match, even though counter-intuitive to "relevance matching".

So, text search facilities are a bit "better" but not "perfect". As always, if you really need more and/or more performance, look to an external solution.

Feel free to try a similar operation with the Mongoose implementation of [**`.find()`**](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.find) as well. But have my reservations from past experience that there is generally some masking and checking going on there, so hence the description of usage with the "native" node driver.

Comment: Neil, this is an amazing answer, but I'm having trouble processing the results.  When I `console.log` docs in the callback, I get these options `{ toArray: [Function],
  each: [Function],
  next: [Function],
  nextObject: [Function],
  setReadPreference: [Function],
  batchSize: [Function],
  count: [Function],
  stream: [Function],
  close: [Function],
  explain: [Function],
  isClosed: [Function],
  rewind: [Function],
  etc...` and when using toArray() I get `[MongoError: Can't canonicalize query: BadValue must have $meta projection for all $meta sort keys`  Do you know what the issue is?